# Change widget state from another widget, a non child widget

Tags: flutter

So i have a side bar to the left of the screen, and it has as an icon. On the right side, i have a widget where I want the data to be displayed when the icon is tapped. The widgets are placed used the positioned widget, each widget in its own container on the homescreen. They do not have child-parent relationships.

I problaby have a bad design lol but nonetheless I would like to know if it is possible with flutter? Maybe with state management? Thank you

Comment: What is the question exactly? Some helpful thing to consider is to share your UI design or the codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, with state management it could work. create a variabile _isTapped = false at the start. if you tap the button use setState to update it to

```
_isTapped = !_isTapped;
```

then when you create your page do something like this and put the container  with data if the button is there, else put the container without anything

```
_isTapped == true? Container(/*with all the data in it*/) : Container(),
```

if that doesnt work do something like

```
Column(
children:[if(_isTapped == true)
        Container(/*with data*/)
else Container()
 ])
```

You can also use SizedBox() instead of the empty container i think is better